# solution for if (count($result) > 0)

Tags: php, database

I use an email confirmation to confirm subscription
everything is working fine except when the email recipient tries to use his key twice.
then the recipient gets an **"fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: count(): Argument #1 ($value) must be of type Countable | array, null given in.. Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in.. "**

In use is MariaDB with php 8.1

this is the code

```
// to ensure the request via POST
require_once __DIR__ . '/lib/SupportService.php';
$supportService = new SupportService();

// to Debug set as true
$supportService->setDebug(true);

$subscriptionKey = $_GET['q'];

require_once __DIR__ . '/Model/Subscription.php';
$subscription = new Subscription();
$result = $subscription->getMember($subscriptionKey, 0);

if (count($result) > 0) {
    // member found, go ahead and update status
    $subscription->updateStatus($subscriptionKey, 1);
    $message = $result[0]['member_name'] . ', Ihre Anmeldung ist bestätigt.';
    $messageType = 'success';
} else {
    // security precaution: do not reveal any information here
    // play subtle with the reported message
    $message = 'Invalid URL!';    
    $messageType = 'error';
}
?>
```

what do I have to do to tell the recipient that everything is done after first confirmation and that every following try to confirm same code will not work ?
thanks for your help

I tried to stop the script with die and also tried this

```
if (count($result) > 0) {
    // member found, go ahead and update status
    $subscription->updateStatus($subscriptionKey, 1);
    $message = $result[0]['member_name'] . ', Ihre Anmeldung ist bestätigt.';
    $messageType = 'success';
} else {
    // securiy precaution: do not reveal any information here
    // play subtle with the reported message
    $message = $result[1]['member_name'] . ', Bestätigung Invalid URL!';    
    $messageType = 'error';
}
```

but nothing happend except the fatal error was still there

Answer (score 0):

Based on the `getMember()` method it accepts a arguments `subscriptionKey` and `status` which means it will return a data that has the given `subscriptionKey` and has a `status` of `0`.Since in the first try when the user click the confirmation, it will naturally return the data. But after the second try it will not find the data since the `status` of the user that has the given `subscriptionKey` is already `1`. In your condition it says `count($result)` which means it will count the data inside the `$result`. In the first try it will not throw an error because it returns an `array of data` but the second time the value of the `$result` is now `null` which means `count(null)` so the error will be thrown. Instead of using `count()` you can check if the `$result` is `null`.

```
// sample code
// it will check ifthe result is not null. you can also remove the '!' if you want.
if(!is_null($result)) {...} else {...}
```